# How to return self in Crystal

Tags: self, crystal-lang

I'm a newbie in Crystal.

I'm trying to return `self` in Crystal, like in this Python:

```py
class Something:
    def some_method():
        # do something
        return self
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: There are two great resources for learning crystal. The first is the crystal docs: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/ -- both an extensively documented API and language reference doc are there. The second resource is to look at Ruby. Crystal draws a lot of it's syntax and style from Ruby, and while the examples don't always translate 1:1, they style of programming often does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little extended example. `say_hello` is called by `self.say_hello`. Just defining `self` returns the object/instance itself, like expected.

```
% cat file.cr
class Something
  def say_hello
    puts "Hi"
  end

  def some
    self.say_hello
  end

  def some_method
    self
  end
end

s = Something.new

s.some

puts s.some_method
```

##### Output

```
% crystal run file.cr
Hi
#<Something:0x102b6de80>
```